# Logstash TLS handshake failure

Tags: logstash, metricbeat

I'm attempting to configure a metricbeat to send data to logstash. I'm configuring both to use SSL (correctly, I think), but I get a tls handshake failure. The specific error is:

```
2020-02-17T19:42:06.411Z    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://elk-logstash-beat:5044)): remote error: tls: handshake failure
```

My beats.conf input is:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/elk/cert.pem"
    ssl_certificate_authorities => [
      "/etc/ssl/elk/ca_root.pem",
      "/etc/ssl/elk/ca_int.pem"
    ]
    ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/elk/key-p8.pem"
  }
}
```

My metricbeat output.logstash is:

```
output:
  logstash:
    index: metricbeat
    hosts:
      - logstash:5044
    ssl:
      enabled: true
      verification_mode: none
```

## Update

I've validated that my `output.logstash` configuration works correctly without SSL configured for both Logstash and Metricbeat.

Additionally, when I update my `input.beats` to the following:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/elk/cert.pem"
    ssl_certificate_authorities => [
      "/etc/ssl/elk/ca_root.pem",
      "/etc/ssl/elk/ca_int.pem"
    ]
    ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/elk/key-p8.pem"
    ssl_verify_mode => "none"
  }
}
```

and my `output.logstash` to the following:

```
output:
  logstash:
    index: elk-metricbeat
    hosts:
      - elk-logstash-beat:5044
    ssl:
      enabled: true
      verification_mode: none
      certificate: /etc/ssl/elk/cert.pem
      certificate_authorities:
        - /etc/ssl/elk/ca_root.pem
        - /etc/ssl/elk/ca_int.pem
      key: /etc/ssl/elk/key-p8.pem
```

...everything works as expected. However, commenting out the following from `output.logstash` makes it fail:

```
      certificate: /etc/ssl/elk/cert.pem
      certificate_authorities:
        - /etc/ssl/elk/ca_root.pem
        - /etc/ssl/elk/ca_int.pem
      key: /etc/ssl/elk/key-p8.pem
```

Based on my understanding, `ssl_verify_mode => "none"` should accept any client connecting via SSL, whether it authenticates or not. Is this correct?

Comment: May be this link is helpful for you ? https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ssl-for-filebeat-logstash-remote-error-tls-handshake-failure/75371

Comment: Thanks, but alas, I've already ticked off the boxes in that post. The Elastic documentation is Pretty Darned Good, but sometimes there are small gaps in it. I'm guessing I'm falling into one of those gaps.